# Doctrine makes many queries for one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 app with Doctrine as ORM. In my app i have two entities with one-to-many relations. The one entity is `User` and the many entity is `Item`. Their relation config goes below:

User:

```
oneToMany:
            items:
                targetEntity: App\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item
                fetch: EAGER
                mappedBy: user
```

Item:

```
manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
            fetch: EAGER
            inversedBy: items
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

The problem is when i'm trying to get the list of `Users` and their `Items`, Doctrine creates separate query for each user to fetch it's items.

The query itself is quite simple:

```
    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppUserBundle:User')->findBy([], [], 30);
```

Is it possible to fetch all related items for users in one query automatically using Doctrine?

I'm using SF 2.7.6 and doctrine libs with versions:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.5.1  Caching library offering an ob...
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.5.1  Common Library for Doctrine pr...
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.2  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.0   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.2.1   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  1.1.1   Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1  Common String Manipulations wi...
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility t...
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that ...
doctrine/migrations                  v1.1.0  Database Schema migrations usi...
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.1  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Comment: Make sure you cleared your cache and that the mapping file you have shown is the one actually being used.  Make you are not mixing yaml and annotations.  What you posted should work.

Comment: I've just checked all this and still no luck.

Comment: Just for grins, try dropping the 30 from your query.  Limits and offsets are always a bit challenging when joins are involved.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think setting eager fetch is a great idea anyway tbh.

Something like this should work fine:

```
$users = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()->select('u, i') // key is to select both entities  
    ->from('YourBundle:User', 'u')
    ->join('u.item', 'i')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: I've managed to to get related records using your answer. It works, technically, but gives a big overhead on data. Let's say i have multiple one-to-many relationships to User entity and want to return 10000 records at once and every user have 10 Items and 10 Accounts. If i will use JOIN method for this it will return 10000 * 10 * 10 records. I would prefer if Doctrine can make 3 separate queries to fetch this data.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [method in the repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#joining-related-records) that performs the joins to avoid the additional queries. It's possible to replace the `findBy` method with your own implementation but my preference is to create methods that are more descriptive.

Although the examples in the Symfony documentation use [DQL](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), you can use the [`QueryBuilder`](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) if you prefer.

Comment: I'm using the query builder, the query in this question used only for simplification, results are the same.

Comment: If you are using the query builder then post the query.  You will need to select both the user and the items.  Makes a big difference.