# Prevent multi result in one-many relation with Symfony querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I have an product entity with an one-to-many relation to its images. When I perform a query on the products and it has more than one images linked I get the product double in my result.

```
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->select('product.id, img.filename')
        ->leftJoin('product.images', 'img')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Is there a way to prevent the double products? Something like group but then on the images.

Comment: It would probably by simpler to get the product as an entity and get its images.

Comment: Maybe but I want for performance prospective get all the info from the product to display it in one query. So in the query I also need the images names and urls. The example is made simple as the real query.

Comment: I think you can declare the relation as "EAGER" and then it will gather all the images in the initial fetch.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33557777/2600812

Comment: what about you yml files or annotations, did you set them up correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get result as entites collection and avoid full hydration you can use [partial obejcts](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html).

Using eager loading can lead to performance issues in other parts, I don't think you need to load images everytime you use a product.